# How to show hours over 24?

Tags: google-sheets

If one sums a number of cells that contains time data, how does one sum it and format it to show hours and minutes and not days?  For example if the times `20:20` & `08:10` are summed, the result formatted by hours and minutes is `04:30`, what is required is `28:30`

How can a cell be formatted to display total hours?

Comment: You can convert it to minutes then divide into hours again.

Comment: hi @Ralphilius, unfortunately converting to minutes cuts of the hours!  So, 01:03, just shows as 3    =MINUTE(SUM(C2:C8))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have these numbers in A1, A2

1. Apply `TIMEVALUE()` to B1, B2
2. `SUM` all these values then multiply by 24 into B3
3. Apply this in any other cell: `=ROUNDDOWN(B3)&":"&60*(B3-(ROUNDDOWN(B3)))`

Comment: Many thanks @Ralphilius, it is a bit of a pain converting but I guess Google sheets can't differentiate between date/time and just time so that makes sense.  It would be good for there to be a separate function but this works so thank you.  I had to add a ROUND statement around the whole of the minutes section there for some reason
=ROUNDDOWN(C9)&":"&ROUND((60*(C9-(ROUNDDOWN(C9)))))